# Updating Django files

Tags: django-forms

I am new to Django, I have just downloaded Django and created a new project using it. The problem is that I am not able to modify or add new files in my new project directory. What is wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

What OS are You using? In what directory did You start your project?? Maybe You don't have permissions to edit this directory